# How can I implement a generic layout with a scrolling fragment container?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have a generic layout for activities with a single fragment:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Most of my activities reuse this layout and just insert different fragments. The fragments are made up of ConstraintLayouts, LinearLayouts, RecyclerViews, etc. If the fragment has a RecyclerView, scrolling works fine. However, if it contains a LinearLayout or a ConstraintLayout, I can't scroll. If I wrap the FrameLayout in a NestedScrollView, then I can scroll the fragments containing a LinearLayout or a ConstraintLayout, but it breaks recycling in the fragments that have a RecyclerView:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

How can I keep my generic layout generic and also have it handle scrolling for any type of fragment it might contain?

Answer (score 0):

There is a property of NestedScrollView Child,

```
setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

But I would strongly recommend do not use a nested scroll view and recycler view together, as it may cause cascading problems! I suggest using ItemViewTypes in RecyclerView for handling multiple kinds of views. just add a RecyclerView with match_parent width and height. then in your recycler view adapter override getItemViewType and use the position for handling what layout to be inflated.